# On a generalized exponential series.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

As we know, the exponential function is defined on real number by

$e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$.

Naturally, one can think of exponential function with series $\{x_n\}$ by

$ e^{\{x_n\}} = 1 + x_1 + \frac{x_2^2}{2!} + \frac{x_3^3}{3!} + \cdots$.

Some condition like boundedness may be necessary to $\{x_n\}$.

Let's add more condition, like $x_n>0$ and all $x_n$ are roughly similar to a positive constant $x$.

The question is this:

if above constant $x \to \infty$ and all $x_n\sim x$ what more conditions are necessary for $x_n$ to be $e^{\{x_n\}} \times e^{\{-x_n\}} \asymp 1$ ?

When $\{x_n\}$ is a constant series, then the definition above matches with ordinary exponential function, and above equation would work.

I hope there exists any keyword or some theory about this problem.

Comment: What is the meaning of "all $x_n$ are *roughly* similar to a positive number $x$"? Does it mean the sequence $\langle x_n\rangle$ converges to $x$? You also clarify what $\approx$ denotes.

Comment: I'm thinking more of $|x_n-x|<\delta$ for all $n$ with $\delta\ll 1$ and then $\approx 1$ would be $1+o(\delta)$ or something like that.

Comment: Seems to work for "bi-constant" sequence $\{x-u, x+u\}$ then $e^{\{x_n\}}=\cosh(x-u)+\sinh(x+u)$ and when developing the product we get $1-2\sinh(2x)u+o(u)$.